# Why use LIKE instead of '=' when SELECTing primary key field

Tags: sql, sqlite, primary-key

In [an online tutorial](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial_app.html#using-bottle-for-a-web-based-todo-list) for bottle, a python-based web framework using Sqlite, I was interested to see that all the SQL samples where a primary key was `SELECT`ed used `LIKE` instead of `=`.

Here's a simple example:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo_id LIKE '1'
```

Is there any rationale for doing this instead of simply doing:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo_id = 1
```

Comment: LIKE is used for pattern matching, = is for equality. different operators. not sure what the first query would do, or means.

Comment: I find your observations like super derogatory. And it's like, just so mean. Like what did valley girls ever do to you?

Comment: What is the data type of foo_id? Your first query treats it as a string; your second query treats it as a numeric. Those queries are therefore not equivalent and might give very different results!

Answer (score 2):

Since the `id` was declared `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, there's no benefit. In fact, it's likely to be slower since `LIKE` like this would result in a table scan instead of using primary key index.

Answer (score 2):

They will produce the same result, but the 'LIKE' one will perform much worse. I did a simple test and here's the execution plan

[image]

EDIT: This is MSSQL because that tool I had handy, but the result will be the same pretty much in any db

Comment: It won't necessarily be the same for other DBMSs because different DBMSs have different rules for implicit type conversions. Also most other DBMSs support different types of index (other than B trees I mean).